# My code is throwing Exception Unrecognized selector sent

Tags: ios, nsstring, sbjson

This is the code I am using to get string coming through a SBJson parsing:

```
NSMutableArray *abc=[jsonData valueForKey:@"items"];

NSString *imgStr=(NSString *)[abc valueForKey:@"image"];
NSLog(@"%@",imgStr);
```

here abc is `NSMutableArray`

and the exception it is throwing is

```
> -[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Show your JSON please. And add an `NSLog(@"%@", abc);` line and show the output of this before the crash. I suspect `abc` is not what you think it is.

Comment: this is the NSLog for abc in my consol  `2013-01-24 16:14:06.535 Drase[1381:11303] (
        {
        gamepoint = 20;
        gid = 365;
        image = "iVBORw0KGgksjallajlasldjlasdjlasjljlajsdlajldal";
        level = 1;
        movie = "<null>";
        status = pending;
        uid = 13;
    }
)` the image is short as it is not coming in the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first line you declare `abc` to be an `NSMutableArray`

In the second line you attempt to access it as an `NSDictionary`.

In your case (and I am guessing here), I expect you have an array of items, and each item is a dictionary with an "image" key.

So to get your first item you might  use

```
  NSDictionary* firstItem = [abc objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can extract your image from that:

<s>NSString *imgStr=(NSString *)[firstItem valueForKey:@"image"];</s><sup>1</sup>

```
 NSString *imgStr = [abc objectForKey:@"image"];
```

<sup>1</sup> see comment from @Stig

Comment: oh! i have no idea about that can you tell me how to access NSMutableArray @HeWas

Comment: @Atul, see my expanded answer

Comment: Please, don't advice using `valueForKey:`. It's the wrong method. Learn to use `objectForKey:` which is the method the OP wants.

Comment: @StigBrautaset - corrected, thanks. I always would use objectForKey - but I was trying to leave the rest of the code as-is so that Atul could focus on the issue that was giving him the error.

Comment: @HeWas Excellent. The reason I say that is that the OP probably wouldn't have been confused in the first place if he'd used the correct method, as the error would have been much more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

1. For NSArray, `valueForKey:` returns another array. It does *not* return an NSString, regardless of your cast. You need get a reference to the first entry in the array, then call `objectForKey:` on that.
2. You're using the NSKeyValueCoding method `valueForKey:` where you're probably intending to use the NSDictionary method `objectForKey:`. For dictionaries they are roughly interchangeable, but if you'd used `objectForKey:` you would have got an easy to understand error about not being able to call `objectForKey:` on an array. **Use `valueForKey:` only when you really want key-value-coding semantics.**
3. You almost *never* need to cast `id` in Objective-C. You're only hiding errors that way. (It may or may not be hiding your problem in this instance, but it's certainly uglier, incorrect (because you're trying to cast an array to a string) and just fooling you into thinking you have a string because the cast didn't fail.)

You probably meant to write something like this:

```
NSArray *abc = [jsonData valueForKey:@"items"];
NSDictionary *entry = [abc objectAtIndex:0];    
NSString *imgStr = [entry objectForKey:@"image"];
NSLog(@"%@", imgStr);
```